# 3D Touch calls viewDidDisappear when popping VC

Tags: ios, 3dtouch

I am struggling around with the peek and pop feature in my iOS app. In the viewDidDisappear method in the VC I want to pop, I have a function to remove some observers related to the model. If I now peek the new VC, it initializes the observers. The problem now is that if I pop the VC it calls the viewDidDisappear method and removes these observers which I want to avoid. I only want to remove the observers if the user cancels the peek action. I already played around with some Booleans but that was no success.

What would be the best way to solve this?

Here is my 3D Touch setup

```
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location) else { return nil }
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) else { return nil }
    guard let detailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PostDetailViewController") as? PostDetailViewController else { return nil }

    let row = indexPath.row

    detailVC.post = self.posts[row]
    detailVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame
    }

    return detailVC
}

func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
    showViewController(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Hey please check my answer i hope you may find a solution from that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like:

```
extension HomeViewController: PeekPopPreviewingDelegate {

    func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        //...
    }
    func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
      let detailViewController = viewControllerToCommit as! DetailViewController
      detailViewController.shouldPresentCompleteMode = true
      navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
    }

}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var isPreviewMode = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if isPreviewMode {
            setupPreviewMode()
        } else {
            setupFullMode()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same situation where i was performing some actions in viewDidDissappear. And came up with the solution below.

**What I did is sending the process to sleep for 0.3 seconds in background mode when the viewDidDissappear is called at that time the function previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) is called there i am taking a singleton bool variable and assigning a true value so after 0.3 seconds in viewDidDissappear going to main thread and checking wether the user has popped or not**

**First Declare a Bool variable in Singleton class as didPoppedByUser**

**Then In ViewController which is being presented**

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    sleep(0.3);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if!Singleton.sharedInstance.didPoppedByUser{
             [Singleton sharedInstance].didPoppedByUser = NO;
            //do your operations here
        }else{
            [Singleton sharedInstance].didPoppedByUser = NO;
        }
    });
});
```

}

**In Main ViewController**

```
-(void)previewingContext:(id )previewingContext commitViewController: (UIViewController *)viewControllerToCommit {

[Singleton sharedInstance].didPoppedByUser = YES;

//your operations
```

}

**For Swift**

```
func viewDidDisappear(animated:Bool){
super.viewDidDisappear(animated);
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
    sleep(0.3);
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if Singleton.sharedInstance.didPoppedByUser == false{
            Singleton.sharedInstance.didPoppedByUser = false;
             //do your operations here
        }else{
            Singleton.sharedInstance.didPoppedByUser = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**In Main Controller**

```
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
Singleton.sharedInstance.didPoppedByUser = YES;
 //your operations
```

}

I am not sure doing like this is a proper coding but it works like a charm. 
Its just a logic from my end accept if it works for you

Thanks